# Can't obtain Real results using NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, complex, chemistry

I am trying to find the critical properties of the Carnahan-Starling equation of state,

$$p=\rho R T\frac{1+b\rho /4+(b\rho/4)^2-(b\rho/4)^3}{(1-b\rho /4)^3}-a\rho^2$$
using this system of equations,

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}=0
$$

$$
\frac{\partial^2p}{\partial\rho^2}=0.
$$

And the following simple code was prepared for Mathematica,

```
P[T_, rho_] := rho R T (1 + (b rho)/4 + ((b rho)/4)^2 - ((b rho)/4)^3)/(1 - (b rho)/4)^3 - a rho^2 

NSolve[
 {
  D[P[T, rho], {rho, 1}] == 0,
  D[P[T, rho], {rho, 2}] == 0
  },
 {T, rho}
 ] // MatrixForm
```

Once evaluated, these results obtained (converted to Latex format for the sake of readability),

$$
\left\{\left\{T\to -\frac{20.4876 a}{b R},\rho \to -\frac{5.13672}{b}\right\},\left\{T\to -\frac{38.7085 a}{b R},\rho \to -\frac{1.69831}{b}\right\},\left\{T\to \frac{0.377315 a}{b R},\rho \to \frac{0.521776}{b}\right\},\left\{T\to \frac{(33.6447\, -16.1071 i) a}{b R},\rho \to \frac{13.1566\, -7.20194 i}{b}\right\},\left\{T\to \frac{(33.6447\, +16.1071 i) a}{b R},\rho \to \frac{13.1566\, +7.20194 i}{b}\right\}\right\}
$$

But the above output contains complex numbers. Using `Reals` in `NSolve`, I tried to remove unphysical results,

```
NSolve[
  {
   D[P[T, ρ], {ρ, 1}] == 0,
   D[P[T, ρ], {ρ, 2}] == 0
   },
  {T, ρ},
  Reals
  ] // TableForm
```

Unfortunately that was not helpful; because, for example one of the answers for $\rho$ was,

```
ρ -> 
 Root[-1024. + 1280. b #1 + 1280. b^2 #1^2 + 64. b^3 #1^3 - 
    20. b^4 #1^4 + b^5 #1^5 &, 1]
```

and the answers for $T$ are much longer.

I am totally unable to interpret this. **How can I tell Mathematica to only return Real results?**

Comment: If `output = NSolve[ ... ]`, then `Select[output, FreeQ[#, HoldPattern[Complex[__]]]&]`.

Comment: Sorry, would you please elaborate on more? I am new to Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You just need to copy and paste. Modify your code so that you have `output = NDSolve[ <code that you already have written goes here> ]`, and then evaluate `Select[output, FreeQ[#, HoldPattern[Complex[__]]]&]`. This selects from your list those pairs of `T` and `rho` that don't have the complex number `I` in them. (Although you will have to get rid of the`MatrixForm` part.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Of course; But I'm new to Mathematica itself too!

Comment: @march Thanks. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: @march You meant `output = NSolve[ ... ]` but accidentally typed `output = DNSolve[ ... ]` at your 2nd comment.

Comment: @Shaqpad We were all new to *Mathematica* at some point. :)

Answer (score 2):

You get a root-expression, because the exponent is 5!

```
{D[P[T, rho], {rho, 1}] == 0, D[P[T, rho], {rho, 2}] == 0} // Simplify
```

[image]

You can only solve the system numerical.

```
P[T_, rho_] := rho R T (1 + (b rho)/4 + ((b rho)/4)^2 - ((b rho)/4)^3)/(1 - (b rho)/4)^3 - a rho^2
Solve[{D[P[T, rho], {rho, 1}] == 0, D[P[T, rho], {rho, 2}] == 0}, {T, rho}, Reals];
```

b and R just as an example

```
% /. {b -> 1, R -> 1} // N
{{T -> -20.4876 a, rho -> -5.13672}, {T -> -38.7085 a, rho -> -1.69831}, {T -> 0.377315 a, rho -> 0.521776}}
```